# UI API called from background thread Group

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

После обновления на swift 4 вылезла ошибка, и не пойму откуда. Подскажите, что да как устранить...

[image: Back - 1461 2 issues, UI API called from background thread Group, UIApplication statusBarOrientation must be used from main thread only, Thread 8, 0 +FlurryiOSUtil canvasInLandscapeRight, 20 start_wqthread, UIApplication applicationState must be used from main thread only, Thread 12, 0 +FlurryiOSUtil isInBackground, 11 start_wqthread]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ошибка Flurry, она исправлена в 8.3.2, Вам нужно обновить Flurry SDK (pod update если Вы используете CocoaPods)

Comment: Предупреждение: 8.3.2 приводит к гигантскому всплеску использования памяти, так что на устройстве приложение сразу же убивается, а в симуляторе порождает странные баги. Релиз отозван. https://github.com/flurry/flurry-ios-sdk/issues/121

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь изменять UI (пользовательский интерфейс) из background потока. Как я вижу из лога, срабатывает событие изменения ориентации статус бара.
Попробуйте обернуть ваши действия в инструкцию, выполняемую в главном потоке:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ... // ваш код, который меняет UI
});
```

Comment: Я сам не меняю статус бар нигде в коде, но использую фрейм SWRevealViewController, в котором есть какие-то манипуляции со статус бар и не мало. Может быть из-за него? Там код на обжективе и, что именно оборачивать, даже не пойму